# Can I install any PHP accelerator with Plesk?

Tags: php, installation, plesk, accelerator

I have dedicated virtual server CentOS 6.3 and Parallels Plesk Panel 11.0.9 on it. And I need PHP accelerator installed on that VM. So my question is is that possible to install any PHP accelerator within Plesk? Or should I have SSH access to the VM?

Comment: Plesk is simply the control panel. while there are some things you can install, things like an Accelerator are going to be best done using cli via SSH. If you have a VM usually you should have access to that.

Comment: thank you for your reply. the hosting company gave me ssh access and I already installed eaccelerator. so the answer is not, one cannot install eaccelerator on pleask.

Comment: That would be correct. You cannot using plesk.